# How to set up Qwt 6.1.3 with Qt Designer on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, qt, qwt

I am having trouble setting up the Qt Designer plugin of the Qwt package on Mac OS, I am writing here to request help for performing a working install of Qt Designer, Qt5 and Qwt.
(OS X 10.13.6, Qt 5.12.0, Qwt 6.1.3)

While other similar questions have been asked before, they either refer to other platforms or are outdated in some way, eg. the answer at [Install and use QWT under Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588418/install-and-use-qwt-under-mac-os-x) no longer seems to work, creating a symbolic link in `usr/local` throws a permission error in the current version of Mac OS.

I also had a hard time following some of the steps in the official [Qwt install guide](https://qwt.sourceforge.io/qwtinstall.html) where it is explaining how to make the Qt Designer plugin to work. I am not entirely clear on how to set the environment variable on my system, or whether that instruction is even applicable. Furthermore, the Qwt documentation links to a [Qt documentation page](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/adding-plugins.html) that appears outdated, as of version 5.12.0 the Qt Creator app bundle has a different structure than what is used in the provided commands. Do I need to perform these steps *in addition to* setting the environment variable, or are these two alternatives?

After encountering these issues, I created a clean install of Qt, Qwt and Qt Creator through Homebrew, and set them up as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219373/cant-install-qwt-designer-plugin-on-mac). The answer here is in essence an update to the instructions provided in the Qt documentation.

I have followed the steps provided in this answer, with the exception that running `otool -L` on existing plugins returned slightly different paths in my case, (`@loader_path/../../Frameworks/` instead of `@rpath/Frameworks/`) - I adapted the commands accordingly.

At this point Qt Designer crashes when opening a form file.

Below is a listing of the commands I used, for reproducibility:

```
brew install qt qwt
brew cask install qt-creator

sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/qwt/6.1.3_4/lib/qt/plugins/designer/libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/PlugIns/designer
sudo cp -r /usr/local/Cellar/qwt/6.1.3_4/lib/qwt.framework /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/Frameworks

cd /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/PlugIns/designer
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtDesigner.framework/Versions/5/QtDesigner" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtDesigner.framework/Versions/5/QtDesigner" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtXml.framework/Versions/5/QtXml" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/Cellar/qwt/6.1.3_4/lib/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/qwt.framework/Versions/6/qwt" libqwt_designer_plugin.dylib

cd  /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app/Contents/Frameworks/qwt.framework
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtSvg.framework/Versions/5/QtSvg" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/QtConcurrent" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/QtConcurrent" qwt
sudo install_name_tool -change "/usr/local/opt/qt/lib/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL" "@loader_path/../../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL" qwt
```

Running `otool -L` at this point confirms that the changes have been made, however Qt Designer crashes while starting (Qt Creator itself opens normally).

What am I missing? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the help in advance!